# Keep table editable until save or cancel button clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to have my table be editable when the edit link is clicked. This portion does work, but I believe that the save or cancel button are being triggered which is exiting out of edit.

```
$(function () {
            $('.edit-mode').hide();
            $('.edit-user, .cancel-user').on('click', function () {
                var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
                tr.find('.edit-mode, .display-mode').toggle();
            });

            $('.save-user').on('.click', function () {
                var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');

                var ExpMonthYr = tr.find("#ExpMonthYr").val();
                var TravelDate = tr.find("#TravelDate").val();
                var triptype = tr.find("#triptype").val();

                tr.find("#ExpMonthYr").text(ExpMonthYr);
                tr.find("#TravelDate").text(TravelDate);
                tr.find("#triptype").text(triptype);

                tr.find('.edit-mode, .display-mode').toggle();

                var LansingMileageModel = {
                    "ExpMonthYr": ExpMonthYr,
                    "TravelDate": TravelDate,
                    "triptype": triptype
                };

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/LansingMileage/Edit',
                    data: JSON.stringify(LansingMileageModel),
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });

            });

        });
```

This is my table that I'm trying to make editable.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Records)
            {   

                if(item.TripType == 1)
                {
                   item.StringTripType  = "One Way";
                }
                else 
                {
                    item.StringTripType = "Round Trip";
                }

            <tr id="@item.RowIndex">

                @*<td><input type="submit" formaction="/LansingMileage/DeleteEntry/@item.RowIndex" value="Delete" name="Deletebtn" id="delete" /></td>*@
                @*@Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.RowIndex }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?');", @class = "delete-button" })
                  <button class="edit-user display-mode">Edit</button>
                <button class="save-user edit-mode">Save</button>
                <button class="cancel-user edit-mode">Cancel</button>  
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="display-mode">
                        @item.ExpMonthYr
                    </span>
                    <label id="ExpMonthYr">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExpMonthYr, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker edit-mode", Name = "expenseDate" } })
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="display-mode">
                        @item.TravelDate
                    </span>
                    <label id="TravelDate">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TravelDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicke edit-mode", Name = "travelDate" } })
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="display-mode">
                        @item.StringTripType
                    </span>
                    <select id="triptype" name="triptype" class="edit-mode">
                        <option value="1"> One Way</option>
                        <option value="2">Round Trip</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
```

I'm wanting the program to wait until the user clicks on the save or cancel link. any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other actions aren't being triggered.  But by clicking a link you are triggering the behavior of a link, which itself has a default action of following that link and essentially refreshing the page context.  Place a debugging breakpoint in your controller's `Edit` action (for a `GET` request) and observe it being reached.

If you *must* use links then in your link click handlers you need to prevent the browser's default behavior of following the link by calling `preventDefault()` on the `event` object that's passed to the handler function:

```
$('.edit-user, .cancel-user').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
    tr.find('.edit-mode, .display-mode').toggle();
});
```

This would be true of any link you want to override.

**However**, ideally you would use buttons instead of links, which semantically don't necessarily have default actions (outside of a form anyway) and are intended for exactly what you're trying to do.

So instead of this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { @class = "edit-user display-mode" })
```

You might have this:

```
<button class="edit-user display-mode">Edit</button>
```

Then you don't need to disrupt the default behavior because there isn't any.  You would just handle the element's click event as you already do:

```
$('.edit-user, .cancel-user').on('click', function () {
    var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
    tr.find('.edit-mode, .display-mode').toggle();
});
```

In short: Use a link when you want the user to navigate to another page.  Use a button when you want the current page to perform custom logic.

(You can always *style* a button to look like a link if you want.  But you shouldn't use the wrong markup semantics as a replacement for customizing the styling.  Start with the correct markup, style from there.)

Comment: I have tried both ways you have suggested and the page is still refreshing

Comment: @DominikWillaford: Can you provide the updated code in the question?  As well as information obtained from debugging, such as what HTTP requests are being invoked in your browser's debugging tools and what controller actions are being reached in your server-side code?

Comment: Right now I added the buttons and removed the links as you suggested, but none of the code is sending a request to the server side  controller. I will update my code above with the change I have made to the code.

Comment: @DominikWillaford: *"but none of the code is sending a request to the server side controller"* - That's the intent, isn't it?  Can you indicate specifically what the problem is that you're observing?

Comment: When I click on the edit button instead of it just enabling editing of the table it is refreshing the page. It should only send information to the controller when the save button is clicked so that can be updated, but the refresh of the page shouldn't happen.

Comment: @DominikWillaford: What exactly is the request that's being made when the page is "refreshed"?  Is all of this inside of a form that's being posted?  If so, is that form necessary?  (It's not being used in the code shown.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199254/discussion-between-dominik-willaford-and-david).